# Construct self-adjoint operator taking x to y

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

Given $x,y\in \mathbb{C}^n$, I need a self-adjoint operator $J$ such that $Jx=y$. It seems intuitive that such an operator would exist. We can always find some operator taking $x$ to $y$ (by letting $x$ be an element of some basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and then defining an operator on the basis elements, specifying that $x$ maps to $y$). But how can I construct this in a way that ensures the operator is self-adjoint?

Comment: You might use a Householder transformation, as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Thanks, that should work for $\mathbb{C}^n$. Does the construction of a Householder transformation work for infinite dimensional spaces as well? The Wikipedia page only explicitly says it works for finite-dimensional cases.